# Check whether two strings are in same case

Tags: c, string

This is my function code. I want to check whether given two string are in same case

```
example
String1 = PEN
String2 = PENCIL
```

the output should be **SAME**

```
example 2
String1 = PEN
String2 = pencil
```

the output should be **NOT SAME**
This is C program code. But not sure it is working correct, is there anyother way to solve this like any keyword to check same case or not. or any other methods to solve

```
int areSameCase(char str[],char str1[])
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    while(str[i]!='\0' && str1[j]!='\0')
    {
        if((str[i]>='a' && str[i]<='z') == (str1[j]>='a' && str1[j]<='z'))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if((str[i]>='A' && str[i]<='Z') == (str1[j]>='A' && str1[j]<='Z'))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
            i++;
            j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not incrementing the loop counters.

Comment: Your loop unconditionally returns after checking the first character. It cannot correctly check strings longer than one character.

Comment: if the character is different you know it's not in the same case no ?

Comment: This task is going to be a ***lot*** easier if you break out tests into separate functions like  `int isLowerCase(char c)` and `int isUpperCase(char c)`. You can then call those functions from `areSameCase()`

Comment: You should clarify: should `"PEN"` and `"STYLUS"` report that they are the same case?

Comment: Should ``"PEN"`` and ``"PENcil"`` be reported as "same case"?

Comment: The basis of your logic should be this. If two characters are of different case, then you can `return 0` because you already know that the two strings cannot be the same case. If two characters match, you aren't yet sure, and you should go on to look at the next characters. If you get to the end of a string without finding a problem, then you can report a match,

Comment: @MisterMiyagi No since PEN is fully in uppercase and PENcil's last characters are in small

Comment: @TimRandall Yes it should return 1 that is YES those strings are in uppercase. The main objective of this program is check whether two strings are in same case that can be upper or lower case

Comment: I would define `enum case {lower, UPPER, Capitalized, MiXeD};`, then write a function `enum case strcaseclassify(const char *)` that classifies a string and returns the kind(s) of case it has.  Then to see whether two strings have the same case, I'd just do `if(strcaseclassify(str1) == strcaseclassify(str2))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `isupper` and `islower`

Example:

```
#include <ctype.h>

int areSameCase(const char str*, const char str1*)
{
    for (int i = 0; str[i]!='\0' && str1[i]!='\0'; ++i)
    {
        int l_a = islower(str[i]);
        int l_b = islower(str1[i]);
        int u_a = isupper(str[i]);
        int u_b = isupper(str1[i]);
        if ((!l_a &&  l_b) ||  // b is lower case but a isn't
            ( l_a && !l_b) ||  // a is lower case but b isn't
            (!u_a &&  u_b) ||  // b is upper case but a isn't
            ( u_a && !u_b))    // a is upper case but b isn't
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Using `bool` you can do it with a bit fewer lines:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int areSameCase(const char str*, const char str1*)
{
    for (int i = 0; str[i]!='\0' && str1[i]!='\0'; ++i)
    {
        bool l_a = islower(str[i]);
        bool l_b = islower(str1[i]);
        bool u_a = isupper(str[i]);
        bool u_b = isupper(str1[i]);
        if ((l_a != l_b) || (u_a != u_b))
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

or even

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int areSameCase(const char str*, const char str1*)
{
    for (int i = 0; str[i]!='\0' && str1[i]!='\0'; ++i)
    {
        if (((bool)islower(str[i]) != (bool)islower(str1[i])) ||
            ((bool)isupper(str[i]) != (bool)isupper(str1[i])))
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: [j] should likely be [i].

Comment: Ah, yes. `isupper` and `islower` return a non-zero value as true, not only `1`.

Comment: If the `int` are swapped for `bool` then it won't matter what `isupper` etc return.

Comment: Btw the parameters should be const correct or the function can't be used with `const char*` etc arguments.

Comment: Could please explain how you done this

Comment: @Lundin Correct. Just copied the function definition from OP and didn't pay attention to `const`. Updated now.

Comment: @imPravinKumar I'm not really sure what more to explain. The code just iterates the characters of the two strings and returns zero when the character case differs. If no difference is detected when either of the strings end, the code returns 1.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** *please don't write code like this if portability is a concern!*

This is a performance over readability solution.

```
bool is_same_case (const char* s1, const char* s2)
{
  // CASE_MASK is a bit mask, always set in ASCII 'a' to 'z', but not in 'A' to 'Z'
  const char CASE_MASK = 0x60; 
  const char cas = s1[0] & CASE_MASK;

  for(size_t i=1; s1[i]!='\0'; i++)
    if((s1[i] & CASE_MASK) != cas)
      return false;

  for(size_t i=0; s2[i]!='\0'; i++)
    if((s2[i] & CASE_MASK) != cas)
      return false;

  return true;
}
```

This code takes advantage of `'A'` to `'Z'` in ASCII encoding having numbers `0x41` to `0x5A` and `'a'` to `'z'` having numbers `0x61` to `0x7A`. Thus the bits in the mask `0x6` is always set in lower case characters, but not in upper case ones. So the code is definitely not portable since it assumes the classic ASCII encoding (...which on the other hand is incredibly common).

To check if both strings have letters of the same case, then none of the strings are allowed to derive from the case of any other given letter. So we can store the bit combination corresponding to the first letter and compare everything else against that.

The code iterates through the first string, checking all letters against the case mask, then does the same for the second string. In case something doesn't match, it stops.

The advantage of this somewhat cryptic code is performance. It doesn't handle the scenario where something isn't a letter, so the checks are faster than the `isupper`/`islower` functions. All in all it's some ~40 instructions when checked on an x86_64, the amount of branching is kept to a minimum and it inspects one string at a time rather than comparing them, which could perhaps be beneficial for data cache usage.

Full test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool is_same_case (const char* s1, const char* s2)
{
  // CASE_MASK is a bit mask, always set in ASCII 'a' to 'z', but not in 'A' to 'Z'
  const char CASE_MASK = 0x60; 
  const char cas = s1[0] & CASE_MASK;

  for(size_t i=1; s1[i]!='\0'; i++)
    if((s1[i] & CASE_MASK) != cas)
      return false;

  for(size_t i=0; s2[i]!='\0'; i++)
    if((s2[i] & CASE_MASK) != cas)
      return false;

  return true;
}

#define TEST(s1,s2) printf("%s %s = %s\n", s1, s2, is_same_case(s1,s2)?"yes":"no")

int main (void) 
{
  TEST("hello","world");
  TEST("Hello","World");
  TEST("HELLO","WORLD");
  TEST("HELLO","hello");
}
```

Output:

```
hello world = yes
Hello World = no
HELLO WORLD = yes
HELLO hello = no
```